# Remove Python 3.5 config-3.5m directory

Tags: python, build, docker

I'm trying to reduce the disk usage of Python 3.5 which is built from source to make smaller docker images. I found that `config-3.5m` and `test` directory inside `/usr/local/lib/python3.5` (total ~80M) took a lot of disk space (~10~20M each).

`test` seems like Python's internal test, but what is `config-3.5m` for? Is it OK to remove those directories?